# IMX6 USB Host controller details

Tags: usb, imx6

I have a system running WinCE7 on an board with IMX6 processor. Occasionally when the system is heavily loaded, I have seen on the USB tracer, that for about 2 seconds , the IN tokens are not seen (only SOF is seen indicating the bus is alive).
Somewhere in the driver the call to the function "IssueBulkTransfer" is made which I believe goes through the Microsoft library and reaches the BSP.
My question is that if I tell the Host controller to send an IN token, will the controller's microcode keep on sending the IN tokens if it receives NAK , without my driver having to resend the IN tokens every time (thus using CPU time)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the description I am assuming that you are talking about EHCI controller.
Answer in two points -

1 - Yes the controller will continuously send the IN Token for NAKs till NAC counter reaches 0 for that endpoint.

2 - The idle period you are seeing is also expected I suppose. Please see the quote from EHCI specification Section 4.9.

> Note that when all queue heads in the Asynchronous Schedule either
>   exhausts all transfers or all NakCnt's go to zero, then the host
>   controller will detect an empty Asynchronous Schedule and idle
>   schedule traversal (see Section 4.8.3).

So the controller will stop traversing the schedule list which might be the 2 secs idle you are seeing. The moment the controller starts traversal again, it reloads the NAK counter and starts in IN token again.

Comment: @AKN - One point I forgot to mention that software can choose not to use the NAK counter. In that case, the host controller will continuously send IN tokens.